# Typescript check for non equality fails in my firebase project (!= and !==)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I somehow do not understand how typescript compares values.

I thought the following snipped would execute the else part since both username and profilePicture values match.

I also do not understand why the lower log message only prints true and false and not the complete text i put in there

```
export const stackOverflowTest = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const beforeUpdate = change.before.data();
        const afterUpdate = change.after.data();

        console.log("beforeUpdate!.profilePicture: "+beforeUpdate!.profilePicture)
        console.log("afterUpdate!.profilePicture: "+afterUpdate!.profilePicture)
        console.log("beforeUpdate!.username: "+beforeUpdate!.username)
        console.log("afterUpdate!.username: "+afterUpdate!.username)

        console.log("profilePicture != "+beforeUpdate!.profilePicture != afterUpdate!.profilePicture)
        console.log("username != "+beforeUpdate!.username != afterUpdate!.username)


        if (beforeUpdate!.profilePicture != afterUpdate!.profilePicture || beforeUpdate!.username != afterUpdate!.username) {
          
           console.log("Executed the if part")
           return Promise.resolve()
        } else {
    
           console.log("Executed the else part")
           return Promise.resolve()

        }

    });
```

Here the firebase log:

```
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest 
  beforeUpdate!.profilePicture: 063729986344.534000000 

    
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  afterUpdate!.profilePicture: 063729986344.534000000
    
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  beforeUpdate!.username: Dennis
    
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  afterUpdate!.username: Dennis

  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  true
    
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  true
    
  7:18:30.286 PM userOnUpdate-stackOverflowTest
  Executed the if part
```

Comment: It's hard to follow along with your log because you seem to have stripped out the relevant log statements in your code.  Please edit the question to show the **actual** code that generates the logs, and explain more clearly what isn't working the way you expect, so we can more easily follow along.

Comment: Have you tried console logging `beforeUpdate!.profilePicture == afterUpdate!.profilePicture` and seeing if `true` or `false` comes out?

Comment: I updated the question with the complete test code. @LukeStorry yes i did. And although the values are identical == returns false

Comment: What are the types of the objects?
Just because they look the same when you are printing them, doesn't mean they are actually the same. You might want to convert to strings or use `JSON.stringify` before comparison.

Comment: I used != so even if they should be auto converted shouldn't they? Also, how can they be different types as they are the same document and literally the same source

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that profilePicture is a Timestamp and you CANNOT compare firestore timestamps using != or any other comparison operation. You have to use Timestamp.isEqual() for that matter. This also (and i don't know why) fixed the error that the username was also inequal.